# Generalise magick::image_apend for multiple image objects

Tags: r, imagemagick

Referring to [Matt Dray's post Quantify colour by {magick}](https://www.rostrum.blog/2018/11/25/art-of-the-possible/), I'd like to generalise the section that **combines** the set of coloured image objects, i.e.

```
# Combine magick objects (coloured squares)
simple_cols <- image_append(c(
  get(col_square[1]), get(col_square[2]), get(col_square[3]),
  get(col_square[4]), get(col_square[5]), get(col_square[6])
))
```

Into something that uses map or similar to do the same with the contents of a vector or list of colours, so that if I have a large no, then I don't need to hardcode as above.

```
simple_cols <- col_square %>% map(get)
```

But this doesn't work as it doesn't return a magick image object, with the following code failing with the error below

```
# Map the simple colours to the image

duplo_mapped <- image_map(
  image = duplo,  # original image
  map = simple_cols  # colours to map on
)
```

*Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.*

Comment: I posted a simplified version on the github site https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/330